# Jenkins handling for environment variables of concurrent builds

Tags: variables, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, environment

I'm just wondering how Jenkins is dealing with environment variables while executing concurrent builds. 
The [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) lists a set of environment variables getting automatically set while Jenkins is executing a build. But how ensures Jenkins the uniqueness of the variables (e.g. build_number)?. Is there a separated environment for each build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes, Jenkins creates a separate environment for each build.

The longer answer is that the build environment variables must not be confused with operating system environment variables. First of all they are variables available to all parts a Jenkins build, like build steps and post-build action. If e.g. a build step launches an operating system process (like the "Execute shell" step launches a Unix shell) then these variables are translated to OS environment variables available to that process. And since the OS isolates each process, there is no problem with concurrent builds.